# AssetUrlSelector examples

Tags: sharepoint

I am looking for an examples on creating AssetUrlSelector in ASP.NET for selecting a document from sharepoint site. Can you please provide me some examples or help links? Since AssetUrlSelector works only on MOSS server/sharepoint server and not on foudation 2010 or wss3.0 how can I  create a a control which is similar to AssetUrlSelector?.

Regards,
Sharmila